# Linking 3rd party libs into lib or exe

Tags: c++, compilation, linker, building

My C++ build process currently looks something like this:

1. Build a static utility lib, link with 3rd party libs
2. Build exe 1, link with utility lib
3. Build exe 2, link with utility lib

Should I instead wait and link the 3rd party libs with the exe:s? Like this:

1. Build a static utility lib
2. Build exe 1, link with utility lib and 3rd party libs
3. Build exe 2, link with utility lib and 3rd party libs

I can see advantages to both ways of doing it. The utility lib becomes self contained in the first case, but the utility lib becomes much smaller (and faster to build) if I link when compiling the exe:s.

Should I link with the lib or the exe:s? Are there any pros/cons I should know about?

Comment: *but the utility lib becomes much smaller (and faster to build) if I link when compiling the exe:s.*, it doesn't become faster to build, it'll grt slower because you'll have to link 3rd party lib 2 times in both .exe-s

Comment: Yes, I mean that the utility lib becomes smaller and faster to build, and my theory was that less data had to be processed/written to disk if the 3rd party code isn't first written into the utility lib and then into the exe:s.

Comment: Oh, I just realized they are static libraries, they will be almost equally fast because static library is just collection of object files.